error "Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined" running folium html file through QWebEngineView
I'm trying to display a HTML file generated trough folium in the QWebEngineView Widget.
The HTML file is running fine when i open it in browser but gives an error when running it with QWebEngineView
Im using a M2 Macbook Air
python - 3.12.3
pyside6 - 6.7.1
folium - 0.16.0
I'm generating the HTML file through the following python code
import folium

loc = [40.713676187303776, -74.01269203808448]
m = folium.Map(location=loc)
m.save("/Users/yasharya/Documents/projects/PySide6/venv/Pyside6_Learn/QWebEngine/map.html")

The HTML file is created directly in directory where the main python code is.
The HTML code generated is
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    
        <script>
            L_NO_TOUCH = false;
            L_DISABLE_3D = false;
        </script>
    
    <style>html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}</style>
    <style>#map {position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;}</style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">

    
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <style>
                #map {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 100.0%;
                    height: 100.0%;
                    left: 0.0%;
                    top: 0.0%;
                }
                .leaflet-container { font-size: 1rem; }
            </style>
</head>
<body>
            <div class="folium-map" id="map" ></div>
</body>
<script>

            var map = L.map(
                "map",
                {
                    center: [28.98603581939582, 77.70582295635853],
                    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
                    zoom: 10,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    preferCanvas: false,
                }
            );
            var tile_layer_1cabcf125de9d18cb7071e63fa140663 = L.tileLayer(
                "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                {"attribution": "\u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\"\u003eOpenStreetMap\u003c/a\u003e contributors", "detectRetina": false, "maxNativeZoom": 19, "maxZoom": 19, "minZoom": 0, "noWrap": false, "opacity": 1, "subdomains": "abc", "tms": false}
            );
        
    
            tile_layer_1cabcf125de9d18cb7071e63fa140663.addTo(map);
        
</script>
</html>

Then i run the main code which run the HTML file
class widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Map")
        self.view = QWebEngineView()
        local_file = os.path.abspath("/Users/yasharya/Documents/projects/PySide6/venv/Test/map.html")
        self.view.setUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(local_file))

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widow = widget()
    widow.show()
    app.exec()

When running the code it shows the following error -> Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined
error
QWebEngineView
Although i get the QWebEngingView the html file is not loaded

I tried asking chatGPT for an solution it give me some code it didn't work
I check QWebEngineView by running some other HTML file it runs fine
I know that QWebEngineView cant run file bigger than 2mb the map file is smaller then that
someone other then me also had this problem it was asked in tht QtForm but it remains unsolved

EDIT
had to remove few lines from HTML file because stackoverflow was marking it as a spam

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors

The same error. Idk, but it's working:
data = io.BytesIO()
self.m.save(data, close_file=False)
self.web_view.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode()) # web_view is an QWebEngineView instance

